# Kotlin: how to override class variable that is a collection as a collection of a subtype

Tags: oop, kotlin

I think the title is confusing so I'll just show some code:

```
open class Polygon {
   open val vertices: List<Point>
   constructor(vertices: List<Point>) {
      this.vertices = vertices.toList()

class Face: Polygon {
   override val vertices: List<Vertex>
```

Where `Vertex` is a subtype of `Point`.

Intellij IDEA inspections shows this warning in the Polygon's constructor:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/W2ItVRn.png]

Is there a more correct way to implement the `Polygon` - `Face` hierarchy with `vertices` being of type list of `Vertex` in the derived class `Face`?

Comment: I suppose the warning is incorrect, because the statement `this.vertices = ...` does not involve any virtual calls that may be dispatched to an overridden member (a `val` does not have an open setter). I reported this to the Kotlin issue tracker: [KT-23170](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23170).

Comment: So it is safe to initialize the property that way, though it's not quite idiomatic. The idiomatic way is to use a [primary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors).

Comment: Thanks for your input, hotkey, always very helpful with kotlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using a generic type

```
open class Polygon {
   open val vertices: List<Point>
   constructor(vertices: List<Point>) {
      this.vertices = vertices.toList()

class Face: Polygon {
   override val vertices: List<Vertex>
```

You could make Polygon have a generic parameter:

```
open class Polygon<T: Point> {
    open val vertices: List<T>

    constructor(vertices: List<T>) {
        this.vertices = vertices.toList()
    }
}

class Face(vertices: List<Vertex>): Polygon<Vertex>(vertices)
```

This way you do not need to redefine the field, which reduces the duplication.

## Using the primary constructor

You can further clean up the code like this:

```
open class Polygon<T: Point>(val vertices: List<T>)
class Face(vertices: List<Vertex>): Polygon<Vertex>(vertices)
```